# adsync not found in jQuery.min.js

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using jQuery and bootstrap in my project.
but in browser console it giving me an error as,

**jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:1111/adsync 404 (Not Found)**

What dose it means ? What can I do to remove this error ?
Does this error affect on my project like working wise ?

Comment: this means that the endpoint was not found, can u share your backend code also if possible. also the frontend code that hits ur backend rest endpoint

Comment: client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

Answer (score 0):

404 (Not Found) error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. Make sure you have  http://localhost:1111/adsync  endpoint.

Comment: yes,true but what is use of adsync ? I have not used in my project. this pointing to jquery.min.js file